# ¿Cómo puedo generar un dataframe que me ordene los datos de otro dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe del siguiente estilo:

```
    |  X  |  Y  |
  0 | x_1 | y_1 | 
  1 | x_1 | y_2 |
  2 | x_1 | y_3 |
  3 | x_2 | y_1 |
  4 | x_2 | y_2 |
  5 | x_3 | y_2 |
```

Y quiero ordenarlo de la siguiente forma

```
      | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 | 
  y_1 |  1  |  1  |  0  |
  y_2 |  1  |  1  |  0  |
  y_3 |  1  |  0  |  0  |
```

¿Existe alguna forma eficiente de hacerlo? Son demasiadas filas, por lo que recorrer los datos uno a uno y generar un nuevo dataframe demora mucho.

De antemano gracias!

Edit: Lo que hice fue crear un dataframe DF2 de solo ceros, en donde las columnas eran los X, las filas los Y,

```
for indice_fila, fila in DF.iterrows():
    DF2[fila['trx']][fila['id']]=1
```

Esto tarda mucho, y mas adelante debo agregar mas filas. Estoy casi seguro que hay una función que lo hace sin recorrer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el siguiente código debería  ayudarte

```
#Importamos pandas

import pandas as pd 

# Creamos el df original
data = {'X':['x_1','x_1','x_1','x_2','x_2','x_3'], 'Y':['y_1','y_2','y_3','y_1','y_2','y_2']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

#Agregamos una columna con 1 esto en todas las combinaciones de X Y
df['Value']=1
#Impimir el df 
df 

#Separamos en columnas los valores de X
df2 = df.pivot(index='Y',columns='X',values='Value')

#Llenamos los NaN "combinaciones faltantes" con 0
df2=df2.fillna(0)
df2
```

Otra solución es la que menciona @ansev en su comentario, me parece mucho más directa.

```
#El siguiente codigo obtiene el mismo resultado que en df2
df3=pd.crosstab(df['Y'], df['X'])
df3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['X'], df['Y'])`